# if else condition in push/unshift javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript Object.

```
var infoHolder = {
 labels: [],
};
```

When i then insert data, i would like to have a condition in my push. such as:

```
infoHolder.labels.push({
 label: 'testLabel',
 image: 'testImage',

 // Condition - Not working!
 if(true) {
 toString: function() { return this.label;}
 } else {
  toString: function() { return this.image;}
 }; 
});
```

Is there a simple solution to this ?
fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t9wqeakL/

Comment: I just can't understand the context of this question, doesn't seem to be OOP standards in JS.

Comment: what i'm attempting should be pretty obvious from this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t9wqeakL/1/

Comment: check you developer console. you have a syntax error there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something along these lines:

```
var infoHolder = { labels: [] }

infoHolder.labels.push({
    label: 'testlabel',
    get image() {return true ? 'testImage' : 'somethingElse'},
    toString: function() {return this.label}
})

infoHolder.labels.forEach(function(d){ console.log(d.image) })
```

Check out [prop getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

Or even more interesting create new/extend `[].push`:

```
function pushTo(target, condition, props){
    // add protection here  
    Array.prototype.push.call(target, condition ? props["label"] : props["image"])
    return target
}

var o = pushTo(infoHolder.labels, 1 == "1", {label: "testLabel", image: "testImage"})

console.log(o)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see two options You may use, depends on the condition itself:

```
toString: condition ? function() { return this.label } : function() { return this.image }
```

... or ...

```
type: condition ? "label" : "image",
toString: function() { return this[this.type] }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it seems you want something like this:

```js
var infoHolder = {
  labels: [],
};

infoHolder.labels.push({
  label: 'testlabel',
  image: function() {
    return true ? 'testImage' : 'somethingElse';
  },
  toString: function() {
    return this.label;
  }
});
console.log(infoHolder);
document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = infoHolder.labels[0].image() + ' <--image() :: toString() --> '+infoHolder.labels[0].toString();
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```